# Make $\frac{a}{b+c} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c}$ right

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this math exercise where I have to make the equation $$\frac{a}{b + c} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c}$$ right. Can anyone help me please? I have already tried things like $$a\left(\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\right)$$

Comment: Are you finding the CONDITION to make the equation "right" ?

Comment: Are you asking for which values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ the equation holds?  Replacing the expression on the left hand side by $a(\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c})$ would make the statement true.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, we can rewrite the equation into:
$$\frac{a}{b + c} = a\left(\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\right)$$

We can see for all $a\neq0$, if $\frac{1}{b + c} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$ holds, the original equation must hold. So any value of $a$ satisfy the equation. we then cancel out $a$:

$$\frac{1}{b + c} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$$
$$\frac{1}{b + c}=\frac{b+c}{bc}$$

For $b+c\neq0,bc\neq0$,

$$(b+c)^2=bc$$
$$b^2+bc+c^2=0$$

Solve $b$ in terms if $c$,we have

$$b=\frac{-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4c^2}}{2}=\frac{-c\pm\sqrt{-3c^2}}{2}$$

If you're seeking for REAL solution, $c=0$ or else $-3c^2<0$ and $b$ is not a real number.

But then $bc=0.$ It contradicts the assumption.

So we have no REAL solutions for $a\neq0$.

For $a=0$, any value of $b,c$ satisfy the equation, so we have

$$(a,b,c)=(0,x,y)$$ where $x,y$ can be of any values.

Comment: A small correction, for $a=0$, it holds for all $b,c \neq 0$. You should include that case. (+1)

Comment: ok. Thx for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

If a is not zero, cancel it out.

If their ratio $ b/c = x$ ,

then, $ x^2 + x + 1 = 0 $

The solutions $ x_1, x_2 $  are two of three complex cube roots of -1, real solution not possible if $ b,c $ are both real.